# Cerrar sesion de firebase al cerrar actividad-Android

Tags: android, firebase

quiero crear una especie de login, que al marcar un checkbox, me permita recordar la sesión o terminar la sesión al cerrar la aplicación si el checkbox esta deshabilitado, para eso utilizo sharedpreferences para guardar el estado del checkbox, pero al ejecutarlo en el método onDestroy de la actividad, el código no se ejecuta, el código de mi metodo onDestroy es este:

```
    @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
            SharedPreferences loginbdd = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String salto=loginbdd.getString("inicio","");
            if(salto.equals("cerrar")){
                Log.d("ONSTOP","EJECUTADO");
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            }
        }

verifique el valor de la preferencia y esta se guarda perfectamente, pero la sesion, sigue sin cerrarse, cabe mencionar que lo probe en el metodo onStop y tampoco funciono
```

espero que puedan ayudarme, de ante mano, muchas gracias

### edit: metodo onBackPressed que mencione en una respuesta

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (snackbar != null && snackbar.isShown()) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar).setTitle("Cerrar Aplicación").setMessage("Deseas cerrar CicloMapp?")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SharedPreferences loginbdd = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String salto = loginbdd.getString("inicio", "");
                    if(salto.equals("cerrar")){
                        Log.d("OnDestroy","EJECUTADO");
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginbdd.edit();
                        editor.remove("inicio");
                        editor.commit();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zhet, prueba ejecutando el super.onDestroy() al final:

```
@Override public void onDestroy() {
    Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
    SharedPreferences loginbdd = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String salto=loginbdd.getString("inicio","");
    if(salto.equals("cerrar")){
        Log.d("ONSTOP","EJECUTADO");
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: lo probé, pero al reiniciar la app, la sesión sigue existiendo, verifique que la preferencia tenga el valor cerrar en un textview, si es necesario, puedo incluir una foto del textview indicando que el valor de la preferencia es cerrar, como esta en ese if

Comment: ¿Se ejecuta el código?, verifica si la condición es evaluada con los datos correctos.

Comment: creo que tienes razon y no se esta ejecutando, sobre el super, coloque un log y este no se muestra

Comment: ¿Como ejecutas el onDestroy?, intenta ejecutar tu mismo código en el onStop() colocando el super.onStop() al final.

Comment: desde que me dijiste que lo moviera al final, si, abajo y con lo del código, lo mismo en ambos

Comment: cree una condicion en el metodo onbackPressed, y el codigo se ejecuto a medias, borro la preferencia, cerro la app, pero no cerro la sesion , agregare el onbackpressed a mi pregunta

Comment: solucione el problema, en el onbackpressed moví la linea de cerrar sesión arriba del editor que borra la preferencia y al reiniciar la app, se cierra la sesión